# Writing just a function that saves given objects to sqlite

Tags: clojure

I am only starting off with clojure, and am stuck thinking how to implement a seemingly straightforward functionality.

There is a function `generator`, which takes (among others) an `saver` function as an argument. The `generator` does all sorts of stuff and generates certain data objects regularly, which need to be saved. This saving is supposed to be handled by the `saver` function, and so the `generator` calls the `saver` with the data that needs to be saved, every time data is generated.

Now, one saver function I am to write is one that saves the data to a sqlite db. How should I go about this?

- One strategy I thought of is to create a connection to the sqlite db in the `saver` function. Create a new connection every time data is to be saved, save the data (only one row in one table) and close the connection. This seemed to be a bit inefficient. Especially considering the data gets generated every 2-5 secs.
- Another idea is to keep an open connection as a module-level var, which is set to `nil` at start. The connection is opened the first time the `saver` function is called and is reused in the subsequent calls. This seems it would probably be more efficient, but to my knowledge, it would require a `def` form inside of the `saver` function. Personally, I don't enjoy doing that.
- One more (crazy?) thought I had was to use an agent that saves the connection object, initially set to `nil`. The `saver` will be a function that `send`s data to the agent. The agent, creates the connection the first time it needs it, and saves in its associated data object. This looks like it might work well, but agents aren't designed for this, are they?

So, how do you people address problem? Is there any other paradigm suited just for this case? Or should I do one of the above?

PS. I spent a good deal of time writing this as it's very hard to put my problem in words. I'm not sure if I got it all right. Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: do you have any ideas how the connection would be closed?  or is that not important - it can just keep comitting?

Comment: It isn't *that* important to me right now, but I am willing to believe that the jvm closes it gracefully when my app closes anyway. Moreover, I'll need the connection throughout the life of the app.

Comment: I do not think you can solve your problem with a def form inside of a function.  A def form defines an immutable binding, regardless of where the def is defined.  You cannot use a def to say, "if this value is null, set it to something non-null, otherwise usevthe current value."

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no such thing as an *immutable binding*. You *can* `def` and re-`def` a var as many times as you like, although it is discouraged. Thing binding to a variable is *not* what is immutable, the object itself that is created is what is immutable. Also, `def` form works inside of a function, http://ideone.com/YTiOI . Ofcourse, I'd want someone better at clojure would confirm what I said :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your second solution sounds best.  if you don't want to use a mutable `Var` (created via `def`) then you could create the connection in a "factory" function as a simple immutable value (so it's just carried around in the closure):

```
(defn sqlite-saver-factory [path]
  (let [db-connection (open-sqlite-connection path)]
    (fn [data]
      (save-to-sqlite db-connection data))))
...
(generator (sqlite-saver-factory path) ...)
```

disclaimer: i am no great clojure expert - the above is just how i would do this in pretty much any functional language.  so perhaps there is a more idiomatic clojure approach.

Comment: *Closures*. Now why didn't I think of that! This is brilliant. Just the solution I need. But as you said, I'm willing to see a clojure-esque approach to it, if different. +1.

Comment: A closure is what I would have recommended if nobody had beaten me to it. Though using an agent to serialize your writes might be a good thing to combine this with, if you don't mind letting them happen in the background.

Comment: Yes, I am ok with it happening in the background. But this use case of `agent` does not involve any mutations to the agent's data object. So, it feels like agents are overkill for what I want to achieve.

Comment: However, I like the prospect of letting it happen in the background. Like `(.start (Thread. saver-fn))`, or is there a better way?